# How to configure callback URL in spring social configuration

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-social, spring-social-google

I am using spring social login. I need to configure a callback URL. By default it is taking localhost as callback URL.

I tried with ProviderSignInController.setApplicationUrl() method. but the changes are not reflecting.

I am using the same code from the spring provided samples. Here is link below.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-sec

I am not able to understand in this sample where the callback URL is defined. If not defined how I can customize that and define some other callback URL. Please Help.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255976/spring-social-connectcontroller-setapplicationurl-doesnt-set-callback-url

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is to allow  callback URL in the settings of social media application.

**What social Media do:**

Social media blocks any kind of attempt to redirect user to some URL which is not allowed there or set proper url in the settings. I think Your current problem is on the social media side. So you follow those github link but set your url in the social media settings for as CallBack URL

Comment: I already added that setting in my application. Now i have to define the callback url in the code.

Comment: Did you use this value="http://localhost:8080/Social/CallBackFB?au=yes" /> in the bean properties